Did Pakistan’s intelligence agency, ISI, use Bangladeshi students to rise against the Sheikh Hasina regime?
A News18 India article on August 5, 2024, titled ISI Conspiracy to Remove Sheikh Hasina as Pakistan Wants Anti-India Govt in Bangladesh: Top Intel Sources reports:

“ISI is using Jamat and their student unit Chhatra Shivir to aggravate the crisis in Dhaka. Jamat is considered to be very close to Pakistan and secret funding was given to them from time to time. They regular get briefings and instructions from the Pakistan mission in Dhaka,” they said.


Bangladesh students’ movement ‘coordinators’ met ISI, US handlers in Pakistan, Dubai and Doha between April and Sept 2023


Batches of Bangladeshi students handpicked as “coordinators”, visited Pakistan, Dubai and Qatar where they met a host of intelligence and security officials, including some from the US, over a period of more than one year, the Indian national security network has learnt after piecing together assorted strands of information within and outside Bangladesh.

Inter-Services Intelligence (ISI) is part of Pakistan's intelligence community. Jamat (banned by the authoritarian Sheikh Hasina regime), and Shibir, a Bangladeshi student organisation, as political groups, are historically Pakistan's allies. So, funding them time to time could be a possibility.
However, has there been special funding in July–August 2024 aimed specifically at the students' uprising?
Was Pakistan’s intelligence agency, ISI, using students to create tension in Bangladesh to deseat the regime?

IDK if this part of an answer, or just repeating the claim but (the India-based) SATP also claims that "The outfit is also reported to be maintaining close links with the Inter Services Intelligence (ISI) [...] The ISI is also reportedly providing substantial amount of funds to the ICS. Other Islamic countries, particularly Saudi Arabia, have provided a major proportion of its financial resources." https://www.satp.org/satporgtp/countries/bangladesh/terroristoutfits/ics.htm

@Believeitornot..., SATP is an Indian think tank based in New Delhi. https://www.satp.org/contact-us

Yeah, I remarked that already. But at least we know the claims [of ISI sponsoring ICS] predate the recent events. They go as far back as 2002 AFAICT https://web.archive.org/web/20020220235700/https://www.satp.org/satporgtp/countries/bangladesh/terroristoutfits/ics.htm
